# How to align 2 views to the left and one to the right in linear layout?

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Learning a lot" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ctv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="  ?" />

                <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thats the code in xml.
I want checkbox and textview next to each other left aligned and seekbar right aligned.I found topics similar to this but I wasn't able to found solution. hmmmmmmm ... Please help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add android:layout_weight="1" to the TextView that will tell the linear layout to give any extra space to the textview, which will move the seekbar to the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Learning a lot" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ctv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will align the first `LinearLayout` (containing `CheckBox` and `TextView`) to Left, and `SeekBar` to right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: seekbar isn't aligned to right... there will be a few of them ... the texts in checkboxes won't be same and that makes it bady designed

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: @MatejLivajić can you show a screenshot as an example of what you want and what you get? :) that'll be easy to understand.